# Display clock in listbox item?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to display a watch among the listbox items ?? The point is that I can switch (if I select it in the listbox) between eg a clock and another string in the listbox and display it for example in some label in my form. As in the picture:
[image]

Every one of my attempts ends with the added time, but it does not refresh.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox3.Items[0] = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    }

    private void clock()
    {

    }
```

Please Help.

Comment: Get the time from server once. Change it in javascript

Comment: Which tech is it ? WPF, WinForms, MVC, WebForms?

Comment: @m.rogalski Windows Form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simplest solution would be to add `listbox3.Refresh()`

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox3.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        listBox3.Items[0] = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    }
    else
    {
        //Nothing in the list so add an item.
        listBox3.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
    }
    listBox3.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: I get an error: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'.'.

Comment: That would indicate there is nothing in the listbox.

Comment: Yes, my mistake, commented too much text. Your solution works !! Thanks